# Why audio of Prince of Persia (1989) produce in CPU rather than audio speaker?

Tags: hardware, gaming, sound

I used to play this [Prince of Persia (1989)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Persia_(1989_video_game)) in Pentinum III computer.
But audio of [Prince of Persia (1989)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Persia_(1989_video_game)) produce in CPU rather than audio speakers.
Why?

Comment: Do you wan't to ask why the sound wasn't produced on a sound card? My guess is that sound-blaster (one of the first widely used sound cards) apparently was released the same year, so they didn't find it worth the time.

Comment: The game supports a variety of sound cards. Either it is not configured properly or the game does not support your sound card. Which sound card you have?

Comment: @Justme The sound card which muted my Windows 98 OS. I don't know proper name.

Comment: Your Windows 98 may not provide a supported virtualized sound device for a DOS session the game runs in. Please don't run DOS games under Windows.

Comment: Prince is Persia is DOS Game? I thought it was assembly language game.

Comment: Being a game intended to run under a certain OS and the programming language the game is written in are two completely different contexts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens presumably because your Prince of Persia installation was configured to produce audio using the PC speaker, not a sound card. In later versions, the setup tool (`SETUP.EXE`) can be used to choose the appropriate sound device:

[image: Screenshot of Prince of Persia’s setup tool, with “Standard PC Internal Speaker” selected]

In earlier versions, the sound device is supposed to be auto-detected, but this can fail, and the default then is the PC speaker. The sound device can be specified as an argument to `PRINCE.EXE` (`stdsnd`, `adlib`, `covox`, `gblast`, `ibmg`, `sblast`, or `tandy`).

In most desktop computers, this would produce sound using a buzzer in the PC case (if it has one!) rather than any loudspeakers or headphones connected to the PC’s audio output.

See [Why did the IBM PC need a sound card?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5833/79) for context.

(Some desktop PCs would re-route PC speaker audio through the sound card, but that was apparently not the case in your computer. The majority of laptops use the same audio-producing hardware for both PC speaker and whatever sound card they have, so this doesn’t happen there.)